# Problem with Google Calendar Api error This app isn't verified

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am creating a project to be able to share a Calendar among some users.
The strange thing is that when one of the users wants to connect, the following error appears telling him "This app isn't verified"

https://prnt.sc/p87wvm

I am not a programmer so it is difficult for me but I think I am doing everything right.

The only api that I am using is that of Google Calendar.

The email with which I am creating the Api is a @gmail.com

https://prnt.sc/p88o0g

I am not using any special scope that requires some type of verification.

I did not exceed any quota limit or anything like that.

And the send to verification button is disabled and tells me that my changes do not require verification

I want any user with a Gmail email to connect to the calendar

What i need to do??

For the doubts I have verified the domain thinking that it was that but it did not solve the problem either

Comment: When you enable the Calendar API in GCP a message suggesting you to generate credentials appear, have you generated the credentials if applicable for your CaseUse?

in [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162) under the verification for apps process it suggests how to get your app verified, there please add all the scopes that you use under the Google Calendar API (whatever is needed in your case)
Then if the Submit for verification is still disabled can you share the text balloon that appears over it?

Comment: Hi Edgardo thanks for your responde, i only use the scopes email/profile/openid, for this scopes Google don't need verification. i dont know why say the app is not verified.
i try to contact google but its impossible.

Comment: [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth) it explains that you need to add some scopes according to the functionality you are adding to your project. Try adding the google calendar scopes and then try to submit it for verification again.